# Google Play Multiplayer Room not Creating

Tags: google-play-services, google-play-games

I have trying to follow the ButtonClicker example. My main activity extends AndroidApplication because I am working with libgdx but I cannot seem to create the room. The code stops after I call "Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.create(getApiClient(), roomBuilder.build())"

I think my problem is somewhere with the getApiClient()
Would love some help understanding what am I doing wrong

See code:

in my OnCreate()

```
  mHelper = new GameHelper(this, 2);
```

When I use anything else other than 2 for the 2nd param the game does not even load

```
protected GoogleApiClient getApiClient() {
    Log.d(TAG, "getApiClient()    " + mHelper.getApiClient());
    return mHelper.getApiClient();  
}
```

calling quick game

```
   private void startQuickGame(){
    Log.d(TAG, "StartQuickGame()");
    //1st param is Minimum players, 2nd param is maximum and 3rd is exclusivebitmask???
    Bundle am = RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(1, 4, 0);

     RoomConfig.Builder roomBuilder = RoomConfig.builder(this);
     roomBuilder.setMessageReceivedListener(this);
     roomBuilder.setRoomStatusUpdateListener(this);
     roomBuilder.setAutoMatchCriteria(am);


     Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.create(getApiClient(), roomBuilder.build());

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);



     Log.d(TAG, " startQuickGame()" +  "createRoom called");

}
```

I tried creating the Game Helper object using "GameHelper.CLIENT_ALL" and I got the following error:

```
                    03-11 09:34:24.083: E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(15954): Parent view is not a TextView
                    03-11 09:34:24.083: D/Launcher(1234): onTrimMemory. Level: 20
                    03-11 09:34:24.083: D/STATUSBAR-IconMerger(950): checkOverflow(1368), More:false, Req:false Child:6
                    03-11 09:34:24.103: W/PopupManager(15954): You have not specified a View to use as content view for popups. Falling back to the Activity content view which may not work properly in future versions of the API. Use setViewForPopups() to set your content view.
                    03-11 09:34:24.103: D/AndroidRuntime(15954): Shutting down VM
                    03-11 09:34:24.103: W/dalvikvm(15954): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41b13898)
                    03-11 09:34:24.103: E/AndroidRuntime(15954): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                    03-11 09:34:24.103: E/AndroidRuntime(15954): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.crazyEagle/com.crazyEagle.MainActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
                    03-11 09:34:24.103: E/AndroidRuntime(15954):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
                    03-11 09:34:24.103: E/AndroidRuntime(15954):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
                    03-11 09:34:24.103: E/AndroidRuntime(15954):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
                    03-11 09:34:24.103: E/AndroidRuntime(15954):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
                    03-11 09:34:24.103: E/AndroidRuntime(15954):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                    03-11 09:34:24.103: E/AndroidRuntime(15954):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                    03-11 09:34:24.103: E/AndroidRuntime(15954):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
                    03-11 09:34:24.103: E/AndroidRuntime(15954):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                    03-11 09:34:24.103: E/AndroidRuntime(15954):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                    03-11 09:34:24.103: E/AndroidRuntime(15954):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
                    03-11 09:34:24.103: E/AndroidRuntime(15954):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
                    03-11 09:34:24.103: E/AndroidRuntime(15954):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                    03-11 09:34:24.103: E/AndroidRuntime(15954): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
                    03-11 09:34:24.103: E/AndroidRuntime(15954):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:320)
                    03-11 09:34:24.103: E/AndroidRuntime(15954):    at android.app.Activity.requestWindowFeature(Activity.java:3338)
                    03-11 09:34:24.103: E/AndroidRuntime(15954):    at com.crazyEagle.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:150)
                    03-11 09:34:24.103: E/AndroidRuntime(15954):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
                    03-11 09:34:24.103: E/AndroidRuntime(15954):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
                    03-11 09:34:24.103: E/AndroidRuntime(15954):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
                    03-11 09:34:24.103: E/AndroidRuntime(15954):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was missing in the manifest

meta-data android:value="@string/app_id" android:name="com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID"